# Location Latitude and Longitude while device is offline in Android

Tags: android

what can be the possible way to find and fetch the Location Latitude and Longitude coordinate values by programming if the android device is offline? is this possible? if yes what can be the possible way? i wants to know in the condition if there is no internet by means no mobile network/WIFI???

Comment: When you say offline, do you mean GPS Disabled or do you mean that it is not connected to GPS, Wifi, or the mobile network.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to start explaining your desired use case. It will be a lot simpler than us explaining the many options that are available to you.

Comment: If you mean offline by no internet connection then you can use GPS Provider It is the best way to fetch the lat lang

Comment: i wants to know in the condition if there is no internet by means no mobile network/WIFI???

Comment: If you are saying no mobile network/ wifi, then you have to go with gps only

Answer (score 1):

Try out following code, It will give you location of from your network provider

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(location==null){
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
```

Or go through this links

[link 1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html)

[link 2](https://newcircle.com/s/post/311/tutorial_android_location_service_example)

Comment: you code gets location from gps provider first than network provider what if there is no internet???

Comment: First it will try to get location from GPS. If gps is off, it will return as null. Thats why I put  `if(location==null)` condition

Answer (score -2):

If there is no Internet connection you can show a alert dialogue which will tell the user to to enable the internet/
Use this code it can help you to enable the internet

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("YOU ARE NOT CONNECTED WITH INTERNET")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("ENABLE INTERNET",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                Intent callInternetsettingIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);

                                startActivity(callInternetsettingIntent);
                            }
                        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }

                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```